# How can I mirror/flip display output?

Tags: display, monitor

For strange reasons best not asked, I have a projector plugged into my computer that is pointed at a mirror. So the computer image is displayed on a wall, but it is mirrored.

In Linux(ubuntu) I can go to display preferences and set the external monitor to have a rotated image. Is there a clever way I could have it set to rotate/flip the image?

Comment: I like it when questions get funky. Let me see what i can come up with. So let me understand the image comes out of the projector, bounces on the mirror and lands on a wall?

Comment: It might depend on the graphics driver you're using. Also, the projector itself might have such an option.

Comment: Yes the image bounces on the mirror and lands on a wall (if I'm honest on a table, hence the wish for a mirror). I first tried finding an option on the monitor.

Comment: It's an option on my projector. I didn't know why anyone would ever use such a setting. Now I know, thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After testing on 2 PCs, I found the following:

On some integrated cards like Intel you can use `xrandr` in console. For example:

Go to console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

- `xrandr -x` will flip de video horizontally like a mirror.
- `xrandr -y` will flip de video vertically.
- `xrandr -y -x` will flip both.
- `xrandr -o normal` will return to normal the video.
- `xrandr -o inverted` will...invert O.o

But if you have an Nvidia this may not work. For an Nvidia to work you need to:

1. Edit you xorg.conf: `sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf`
2. Find the section that has **Driver "nvidia"** in it
3. Copy and paste the following at the end of that section: **Option    "RandRRotation" "on"**

This will activate the rotation for Nvidia which comes off by default. Why off by default i do not know.

After that reboot and you can change the orientation BUT NOT the reflection. What i mean with this is that Nvidia does not yet support reflection options like `-x` or `-y` options in `xrandr`. I will keep searching for some more since the question is interesting.

Comment: If you are testing this sort of thing without the mirror set up, then I suggest first entering `xrandr -o normal` so you can press up,up,enter without twisting your head. :)

Comment: I like your attitude to funky questions. Using `xrandr -x` worked, but it would turn off the primary monitor (which I wanted to use unflipped). Anyway you led me to `xrandr --help` and after some thinking came to the following command which does what I want.
    `xrandr --output VGA1 --reflect x`

Comment: I just spent entirely way too much time playing with this and laughing manaically. I think I have spent too much time in front of my screen today.

Comment: It's 2021 now and it works with NVIDIA as well.