# How to horizontally flip display?

Tags: display, screen, settings

How do I horizontally flip the display, in order for everything to look mirrored?

[image: example]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I mirror/flip display output?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19936/how-can-i-mirror-flip-display-output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
xrandr -x
```

for flipping the video horizontally,

```
xrandr -y
```

for flipping the video vertically.

A few references:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr

https://xorg-team.pages.debian.net/xorg/howto/use-xrandr.html

https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xrandr.1.html